# Chrome Inspector - Dimensions removed?

Tags: google-chrome, dimensions, inspector

Does anyone else have the problem that since yesterday in Chrome the dimensions of the browserwindow aren't shown anymore?

Could this come from an Chrome Update or is it a problem only of my browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this issue to. Because I use it every day it's critical for me. This may help you:
https://gist.github.com/mrpapercut/7a004210306b62dcf813

But I think it's just a f***up and they roll back it soon.

Comment: Thank you! I was not sure if it's my own fault, but now i know it comes from an update. Yeah, I hope too that they will roll it back. It's very important for my daily work!

Answer (score 1):

In version 48.0.2564.116 the dimensions are shown in the page only while I am actively resizing the window with the developer tools open -- they disappear after a short delay.  Version 49.0.2623.87 (current as I post this) removes this tooltip.

You can force the dimensions to be visible at all times by turning on "Device Mode" (the iPhone-looking button second from the left in the developer toolbar.)

Comment: Yes, I'm on V 49 - this seems to remove the feature. Thanks for your answer, the device mode is a useful workaround for this issue.